# showing "Module com.google.common not found, required by org.seleniumhq.selenium.chrome_driver" error while running selenium

Tags: eclipse, selenium-webdriver, automation

[Please help me to solve this issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6neYQ.png)

I did check all the answers in stackoverflow but not found any solution

Comment: youre probably missing this library. try to add it to your project https://github.com/google/guava/releases/tag/v31.1

Comment: Delete your `module-info.java` file (if needed you can recreate it later via right-click on project and _Configure_) or [in `module-info.java` add the required `requires ...;` statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform_Module_System#Properties_of_modules). Also delete your run configuration (_Run > Run Configurations..._) and try again.

Answer (score -1):

```
Please try with the below solutions, recently chrome was updated from the 110 to 111 and Selenium API was forbidden for this version.

ChromeOptions opt=new ChromeOptions();
        opt.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
        //Launching the browser
        driver=new ChromeDriver(opt);

please let me know if it's worked for you.
```

Comment: thanks, can you please tell me where to add this?

Comment: Just define like this before initialization the chrome >ChromeOptions opt=new ChromeOptions();
        opt.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
        //Launching the browser
    Webdriver driver=new ChromeDriver(opt);